# Htaccess when put '/' in the end of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im doing a website with only one page and I want do put in url like: "`http://test.com/portfolio`" and my htaccess to access the same page like `http://test.com/#portfolio`, I already get this with the code below, but when I put `http://test.com/portfolio/`, with '`/`' after, the server open the same page, but without css, links with images... The browser show only the html code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^portfolio(.*)$ #portfolio
    RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ #contact

</IfModule>
```

You know something to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you css and images are dynamically linked (doesn't start with a `/`). This means when you go to:

```
/portfolio/
```

The relative URI base changes from `/` to `/portfolio/`. Which means if you had an image linked like:

```
src="images/foo.jpg"
```

instead of loeading `/images/foo.jpg`, you load `/portfolio/images/foo.jpg`.

Either change your links so that they're absolute links (starts with `/`) or add this to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```